# Can use a spell to infuse an item into a weapon or a weapon with ammo. (A Gun with fireball bullets or a Sword with Blindness/Deafness)

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, artificer-infusions

I sort of want to do the things in the title like having a shotgun with a fire resistant build so I can have ammunition that can use fireball (multiclassing as a Artificer and a sorcerer balancing both out).

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. This is a fairly straightforward question about Artificer class abilities and their Spellcasting feature.

Comment: @nick012000 it was closed at the time because it also had a totally unrelated question. "Need more focus" shouldn't be an issue anymore. Although after reading it multiple times, I'm still failing to understand what the question is asking. If someone understands and could reformulate with clearer english, it would be great and perfectly answerable.

Comment: @Matthieu I think the question is if a multiclass Sorcerer Artificer can infuse spells into weapons. But the asker should clarify if I am right.